# amazon dynamoDb ValidationException

Tags: c, amazon-dynamodb, libcurl, aws-sdk

I am executing following dynamoDB query param using aws-dynamo library in C.

```
{ "TableName": "table4", "KeyConditionExpression": "#yr = :yyyy and ts between :letter1 and :letter2", "ExpressionAttributeNames": { "#yr": "userid" }, "ExpressionAttributeValues": { ":yyyy": "abc", ":letter1": 1, ":letter2": 2 } }
```

But i got error

```
"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"1 validation error detected: Value null at 'hashKeyValue' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"
```

this is my table structure

```
 table4
{
    "Table": {
        "TableSizeBytes": 66,
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "userid",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "ts",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "CreationDateTime": 1464617195.039,
        "ItemCount": 3,
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "ts",
                "AttributeType": "N"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "userid",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1,
            "LastDecreaseDateTime": 1464683346.007,
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 1
        },
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "TableName": "table4",
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:456456456:table/table4"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the partition key and sort key of the table? Have you included the partition key field in the KeyConditionExpression?

Comment: partition key = userid, sortkey= ts

Answer (score 0):

Partition key is must in keyconditionexpression. Please include the partition key and try. When you query the dynamodb, partition key is must. When you scan the dynamodb, partition key is optional. This is the main difference between query vs scan in dynamodb.

Comment: i allready added partition key (userid) in my keyconditionexpression.

Comment: Could you please run the describe table command and paste the table structure here?

Comment: i added table structure in my question

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working query and table structure.

```
{ TableName: 'table4',
KeyConditionExpression: '#userid = :userid AND #ts between :ts1 AND :ts2',
ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#userid': 'userid', '#ts': 'ts' },
ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':userid': 'user1', ':ts1': 1, ':ts2': 2 } }
```

Query output:-

```
{"userid":{"S":"user1"},"ts":{"N":"1"}}
```

Table Structure:-

```
    {"Table":{"AttributeDefinitions":  
      [{"AttributeName":"userid","AttributeType":"S"},
     {"AttributeName":"ts","AttributeType":"N"}],
"TableName":"table4","KeySchema":
[{"AttributeName":"userid","KeyType":"HASH"},{"AttributeName":"ts","KeyType":"RANGE"}],
"TableStatus":"ACTIVE",
"CreationDateTime":"2016-05-31T12:46:08.351Z",
"ProvisionedThroughput":{"LastIncreaseDateTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","LastDecreaseDateTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","NumberOfDecreasesToday":0,
"ReadCapacityUnits":10,"WriteCapacityUnits":10},
"TableSizeBytes":15,"ItemCount":1,"TableArn":
"arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/table4"}}
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If yes, could you please accept the answer?